# remove_if from a std::vector of shared pointers with a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, idioms

How can I delete the elements of a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PTile>> ptiles` fullfilling the condition `ptile->hasNoRegions()`? I've been trying to use `remove_if` for this, but the `Predicate` uses a data member of the object, not the pointer. How do I set the predicate to the function if the elements are smart pointers to the object?

What I have at the moment

```
    ptiles.erase(std::remove_if(ptiles.begin(), ptiles.end(), &PTile::hasNoRegions), ptiles.end());
```

where `hasNoRegions` is a member function of `PTile`. Which obviously doesn't work since I have a `std::shared_ptr<PTile>`, not a `PTile`.

I'm using MSVC 2013.

Comment: The elements are referenced by other objects, so they are shared. I am removing them from a particular vector, but they will survive ♫. Also, `std::unique_ptr` is non.copyable, so I can't have a `std::vector` of `unique_ptr`, am I right?

Comment: vector requires the elements to be moveable. Maybe you just want to pass raw references or pointers around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably wouldn't work even if the vector weren't storing pointers, since member functions take `this` as an implicit argument, and the code wouldn't generate.

You need to write a functor or a lambda that explicitly handles `std::shared_ptr`.

```
ptiles.erase(
    std::remove_if(ptiles.begin(), ptiles.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<PTile> const& ptr) {
        return ptr->hasNoRegions();
    }), 
    ptiles.end()
);
```

Alternative, if you don't have lambdas:

```
//Outside method
bool should_remove_ptile(std::shared_ptr<PTile> const& ptr)  {
    return ptr->hasNoRegions();
}

//inside method

ptiles.erase(std::remove_if(ptiles.begin(), ptiles.end(), should_remove_ptile), ptiles.end());
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have lambdas. +1 for the `auto` expansion and the non-lambda solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying to use `remove_if` for this, but the `Predicate` uses a data member of the object, not the pointer.

What pointer? You will need to use a lambda, as passing a member function pointer is not supported:

```
ptiles.erase(std::remove_if(ptiles.begin(), ptiles.end(), [](const auto& value) {
    return value->hasNoRegions();
}), ptiles.end());
```

Due note that MSVC 2013 has poor modern C++ support, so you might need to write a functor instead of a lambda, or don't use `auto` in a lambda.

Comment: *"In C++17, your code should compile just fine, because of `std::invoke`."*  This is news to me - source? I tried it but it [does not compile neither on g++7 nor on clang++5](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3AjoEjmBSpFHFkEx).

Comment: Ok, I'll go with lambdas. Your example is clear to me. (btw I thought it was MSVC 2012, but it's 2013)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I wrongly thought that `std::invoke` would be used for algorithms, but this is not the case: [see this section](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#6). Thanks!